# How to copy rows checkbox checked as unchecked in jquery?

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/zUAQC/11/

In this sample,

In javascipt box's sampleDiv,I add the next input checkbox .
  In result view,when I checked checkbox and click copy button, copy rows checkbox as checked.
  I wanna get checkbox as unchecked if checked or unchecked it.

Comment: You don't have any `checkbox` over there!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#checkboxid').prop('checked', false);
```

Updated to use prop as per Stefan's comment.

```
    $('#checkboxid')[0].checked = false;
```

as another alternative.

Comment: Using `prop()` might be better than `attr()` in this case. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var sampleDiv = '<div class="sample"><input type="checkbox" /><input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete"><input type="button" value="Add" class="add"/><input type="button" value="Copy" class="copy"/></div>';

$('.test').append(sampleDiv);

$('.delete').live('click',function(){
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
$('.add').live('click',function(){
    $('.test').append(sampleDiv);
});
$('.copy').live('click',function(){
    var $div = $(this).closest('div').clone();
    $('input[type=checkbox]', $div).prop('checked', false);
    $div.appendTo($('.test'));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zUAQC/49/)

Things to note:

- You had a 'textbox' not a `checkbox` in your JSFiddle...
- You didn't delete the div with the delete button, use `remove` for deleting DOM elements not `hide`
- `live` is deptecated. use `delegate` for JQuery 1.4.3+ or `on` for JQuery 1.7+